# Amazon Mechanical Turks Qualification Multiple Locals

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to define a worker qualification for a HIT via command line tool.

The requirements to workers are

- Locale: US, CA
- Number of accomplished HITs >= 30
- Acceptance rate >= 75%

The following is the part of `external_hit.properties` file

```
# Worker_PercentAssignmentsApproved > 75%
qualification.1:000000000000000000L0
qualification.comparator.1:greaterthan
qualification.value.1:75
qualification.private.1:false

# Worker_Locale
qualification.2:00000000000000000071
qualification.comparator.2:in
qualification.LocaleValue.2.Country.1=US
qualification.LocaleValue.2.Country.2=CA

# Worker_NumberHITsApproved > 30
qualification.3:00000000000000000040
qualification.comparator.3:GreaterThan
qualification.value.3:30
```

The problem is I am not sure about the syntax, especially about this part, I made up this part.

```
qualification.LocaleValue.2.Country.1=US
qualification.LocaleValue.2.Country.2=CA
```

I didn't find any example in command line tool format with multiple locales.

I appreciate if you could check the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is a set of comma-separated values:

```
qualification.LocaleValue.2.Country=US,CA
```

However, AWS does not update the command line tools (and the last time I looked, they appeared to be officially unsupported), so this feature may not work at all, thus requiring you to go through the web API.